# What is the difference between setEuler and rotX, rotY, rotZ?

Tags: java, java-3d

I looked a bit on the description of [Transform 3d](http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.3.2/javax/media/j3d/Transform3D.html) but I can't say I really understood what is the difference between [setEuler](http://download.java.net/media/java3d/javadoc/1.3.2/javax/media/j3d/Transform3D.html#setEuler%28javax.vecmath.Vector3d%29) and rotX, rotY and rotZ.
I also searched [some archives](http://markmail.org/message/wi6g6sl4ycstqlrh), but none actually gave me an understandable answer.

Does anyone know what the difference is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're essentially just shorthands:

`t.setEuler(new Vector3d(a, 0, 0))` ⇔ `t.rotX(a)`
`t.setEuler(new Vector3d(0, a, 0))` ⇔ `t.rotY(a)`
`t.setEuler(new Vector3d(0, 0, a))` ⇔ `t.rotZ(a)`